# How to filter data according to the alphabet clicked in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a set of buttons from A to Z when I click on a particular alphabet the brands that contains that alphabet should display as shown in this [link](https://www.carid.com/shop-by-brand/). I have created an array and set the state of all values in variable called `brandSortData` as shown in below code

```
createBrandsMapData(){
    let brandData = {}
    brandList.map((key) => {
        brandData[key] = this.state.items.filter((currentValue) => {if(currentValue.value[0] === key) return currentValue}) 
    })
    this.setState({
        allBrands: brandData,
        brandSortData: brandData
    })
}
```

I have this below `handleClick()` below

```
handleClick = event =>{
    const brandValues = event.target.value
    if(event.target.value === "all"){
        return this.getBrands()
    }
    else{
        console.log(this.state.brandSortData)
        let brandSortDataByCharacter = this.state.brandSortData.filter((currentCharacter) => {if(currentCharacter.value[0] === brandValues) return currentCharacter})
        return brandSortDataByCharacter
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in the `filter()` as `Uncaught TypeError: _this.state.brandSortData.filter is not a function`. I have this `getBrandSortData()` where the buttons are generated

```
getBrandSortData(){
    return(
        <div className="BrandPageList_AlphabetContainer">
            <button value="all" className="BrandPageList_AllButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>All</button>
            {brandList.map((item,index) => 
                <button value={item} key={index} className="BrandPageList_AlphabetButtons" onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</button>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

How do I solve this I am stuck here. This is the format of `brandData` as in image

[image]

Comment: Your `brandData` defined as an object, should be an array

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I updated `brandData` as an array but when I click on alphabet Its returning an empty array

Comment: What is data format of `brandList` ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Please check the updated image in the question

Comment: I don't think you need `brandData` at all, You can just filter your brand list upon a click of an alphabet button. That's why I asked about the `brandList`, not `brandData`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky `brandList` is an array `let brandList = 'ABCEDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing object in your `brandSortData` state that's why you are facing error.

So either change it to store array or change your `handleClick` function like below:

```
handleClick = event =>{
    const brandValues = event.target.value
    if(brandValues === "all"){
        return this.getBrands()
    }
    else{
        let brandSortDataByCharacter = this.state.brandSortData[brandValues]
        return brandSortDataByCharacter
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it worked but I am not able to render the data filtered

Comment: To render `brandSortDataByCharacter` you need to store in state and then use that state